# Getting error NaN when use parseFloat in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get average rating reviews from other people in my project but i'm getting error NaN

Here is my code base from project:

```
const UserFound = ({ userObj, skill }) => {
  // State
  const [showPreview, setShowPreview] = useState(false);
  // const [canInvite, setCanInvite] = useState(false);

  const toggleUserPreview = () => {
    setShowPreview(!showPreview);
  };

  const { Ratings, Skills } = userObj;

  const totalRating = Ratings.reduce((total, rating) => parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(rating.skillset_rating), 0) / Ratings.length;

  // Build skillset string
  const skillsetStr = useSkillset(userObj.Skills);

  const skillElement = (  
      <h4 className="header header--user_card_skill">
      {skill === undefined ?
      <div>
        {
          userObj.Skills.length > 0 ?
            <div>
              {Skills.map((skillName, index) => <div key={index} className="user-skill"> {skillName.skill} </div>)}
            </div>
            : <div>{skillsetStr}</div>
          }
        </div>
        : skill}
      </h4>
  );

  return (
    <>
      <button className="button--result_wrapper" onClick={toggleUserPreview}>
        <div className="container--user_display">
          <div className="container--user_card_top">
            <img
              className="image image--search_avatar"
              src={userObj.picture}
              alt="Avatar"
            />
            <h3 className="header header--user_card_name">
              {userObj.fullname}
            </h3>
            <div className="header header--user_card_bio">{userObj.bio}</div>
          </div>
          <hr className="hr--dashboard_page_break" />
          <div className="container--user_card_bottom">
            {/* {canInvite && <InviteButton userObj={userObj} />} */}
            <div className="user_rating_data">
              <span className="user_rating_data_name">Skillsets:</span>
              <span className="review_unspecified">{skillElement}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="user_rating_review">
              <span className="user_rating_data_name">Reviews:</span>
            {
                userObj.Skills.length > 0?
                <div className="review_rating_star">
                    <Rating value={totalRating} precision={0.5} readOnly max={5} className="user_rating_found" />
                    <span className="user_total_rating">{totalRating}</span>/5
                </div>
                : <div className="review_unspecified">Not enough rating yet</div>
            }
            </div>
          </div>
          <button className="user-card-message_me_button" type="button">Message Me</button>
        </div>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default UserFound;
```

This is how my project look like on web application:

[image]

and this is the result when I do console.log(totalRating):

2.5

2

4

NaN

How can i fix this error?

Thank you. I really appreciate it for your help.

Comment: If there are no ratings yet, `Ratings.length` will be 0 and you are dividing by `Ratings.length`